# How to change the slider revolution height in html?

Tags: html, css, slider-revolution

I got free html themes with slider revolution. I can't figure it out how to change the height of the slider. Could you please help how to reduce te height of the slider?

Here is the code

```
<section id="slider" class="slider-element revslider-wrap full-screen clearix">
    <div id="rev_slider_10_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container" data-alias="fashion1" style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;">

        <div id="rev_slider_10_1" class="rev_slider" style="display:none;" data-version="5.0.7">
            <ul>

                <li data-index="rs-36" class="dark" data-transition="fadetoleftfadefromright" data-fstransition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-easein="Power4.easeInOut" data-easeout="Power4.easeInOut" data-masterspeed="2000" data-thumb="" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Enjoy Nature" data-description="">

                    <img src="demos/spa/images/slider/1.jpg" style='background-color:#ffffff' alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-shape tp-shapewrapper   tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" id="slide-36-layer-4" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-width="full" data-height="full" data-whitespace="normal" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-start="1000" data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 5; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)">
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption -  " id="slide-35-layer-1" data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['40','40','40','40']" data-y="['bottom','bottom','bottom','bottom']" data-voffset="['40','40','40','40']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-style_hover="cursor:pointer;" data-transform_in="y:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"next","delay":""}]' data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="off" data-responsive="off" style="z-index: 5; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 20px; line-height: 22px; font-weight: 400;padding:3px 8px 3px 8px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-radius:30px 30px 30px 30px;"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption Fashion-BigDisplay   tp-resizeme" id="slide-36-layer-5" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['255','231','211','62']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-30','-18','-48','-28']" data-fontsize="['80','50','50','56']" data-lineheight="['100','50','50','50']" data-width="['none','265','265','265']" data-height="['none','100','100','100']" data-whitespace="['nowrap','normal','normal','normal']" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="x:[100%];s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 9; white-space: nowrap;">Spa Treatment
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption Fashion-TextBlock   tp-resizeme" id="slide-36-layer-6" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['189','219','200','39']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['120','130','80','110']" data-fontsize="['20','17','17','17']" data-lineheight="['40','30','30','30']" data-width="219" data-height="161" data-whitespace="normal" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="x:[-100%];s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 10; min-width: 219px; max-width: 219px; max-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; white-space: normal;"><i class="icon-line-check"></i><br>
                    <i class="icon-line-check"></i><br>
                    <i class="icon-line-check"></i><br>
                    <i class="icon-line-check"></i><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption Fashion-SmallText   tp-resizeme" id="slide-36-layer-7" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['105','130','105','-39']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-85','-85','-110','-95']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 11; white-space: nowrap;">UNISEX
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption Fashion-TextBlock   tp-resizeme" id="slide-36-layer-8" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['224','254','230','80']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['120','130','79','110']" data-fontsize="['20','17','17','17']" data-lineheight="['40','30','30','30']" data-width="219" data-height="161" data-whitespace="normal" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="x:[100%];s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 12; min-width: 219px; max-width: 219px; max-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; white-space: normal; font-weight: 600;">Body Scrub<br />
                    Body Wrap<br />
                    Thai Therapy
                    Baliness Massage<br />
                    </div>
                </li>

                
            </ul>
            <div class="tp-bannertimer tp-bottom" style="visibility: hidden !important;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I did not try anything. Don't know how to do it